# How to increment value in the database when the button is click PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

How to increment value in the database when the button is clicked

```
function getPro(){
    global $con;
    $sada = "select * from products order by asd";
    $sdasdasa = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);
    while ($asdasd = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
```

Comment: That means that code works 5 times.

Comment: Do you have 5 products in `products` table ?

Comment: yes i have 5 products in the table

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code runs iteratively or 5 times due to some issue.

Most probably, your *If statement* (in which update code is placed) is in body of some loop. Either you have not closed the body of some loop undesirably or something like that.